# Chrome headless mode stuck on listening on ws

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I've recently decided to work on a simple web scraper, using python and selenium. Yet, I've stumbled upon a problem i cannot manage to resolve. My script works perfectly fine in normal Chrome mode, but if I use headless mode, it gets stuck and just prints:

```
Devtools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60870/devtools/browser/the_rest_of_the_symbols
```

The code looks like that:

```
options = opt.get_options()
    opt.set_headless_mode(options)
    opt.set_incognito_mode(options)
    opt.set_fullscreen(options)
    opt.set_ignore_certificate_error(options)

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER, options=options)
    browser.get(TARGET_URL)

    search_bar = WebDriverWait(browser, 120, 1).until(expect.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='What are you looking for?']")))
    print(chosen_item)
```

Has anyone ever experienced something like that? I updated my Chrome and double checked driver's version but it didn't help.

Here is the snippet for those, who want to try and reproduce the error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as expect
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

DRIVER = ".\\chromedriver"
TARGET_URL = "https://www.x-kom.pl"


def perform_search():
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_argument("--incognito")
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER, options=options)
        browser.get(TARGET_URL)

        search_bar = WebDriverWait(browser, 120, 1).until(expect.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Czego szukasz?']")))
        print(browser.current_url)
        print(browser.title)
        search_bar.send_keys('Monitor')
        search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    perform_search()
```

Remember to update driver's path.

Comment: You are asking it to wait 2 minutes in WebDriverWait() - have you seen what happens after 2 minutes?

Comment: A bunch od error messages such as: `Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer`.

Comment: Please include a minimum reproducible snippet of code that will allow me to reproduce your problem, then I have some chance of helping.

Comment: Added the snippet to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your script wasn't working, but I made some adjustments and the below script, at least, runs on my machine:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as expect
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
DRIVER = ".\\chromedriver"
TARGET_URL = "https://www.x-kom.pl"


def wait_for_load(element_id, browser):
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, element_id))
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(element_present)


def perform_search():
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_argument("--incognito")
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER, options=options)
        browser.get(TARGET_URL)
        wait_for_load("app-Footer", browser)
        search_bar = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Czego szukasz?']")
        print(search_bar.tag_name)
        search_bar.send_keys('Monitor')
        search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    perform_search()
```

It prints the name of the input_tag ("input") retrieved by the placeholder find (showing that it is, indeed, locating the correct element).

On my machine it appears, also, to send the keys appropriately. Let me know if it works on yours.